# Access Ethernet-connected server on a local network

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, debian

I am trying to set up my Banana Pi as a web server for my local network.
Due to bad Wi-Fi signal, I connected my Banana Pi to the PC and added a shared connection for the Wi-Fi adapter.

Currently I am able to access the web server from the PC, but my goal is to be able to access it from different devices on the same Wi-Fi network too.
Is this possible without connecting the server directly to the router?

The PC is running Windows 10 and the server is running Debian.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

[Heres a picture of what i am trying to accomplish (cant embed it yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUrHT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible .

You must create a  **a Network Bridge connection** and add the Wifi adapter and the Lan adapter .